# How to prevent negative margin pushing element outside parent

Tags: html, css, position, margin

I need to position a child element vertically with negative margin, to have it positioned higher than it's sibling. However, this pushes it outside the parent (CHILD 2 in the example below).

[image]

Is there any way to expand the parent, such that when there's negative margin on a child element, the parent will visually still encapsulate it's children?

```css
.parent {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  display: flex;
}
.child1 {background-color: pink;}
.child2 {
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">CHILD 1</div>
  <div class="child2">CHILD 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how you want to position your element? it's clear that you should use something different from negative margin

Comment: why not *positive* margin on the first child? or bigger height for the second child?

Comment: Hm, that could actually be a way to solve my problem.